# Is it possible to create (render) animated transparent filters?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I would like to know if it is possible to render a transparent animation in Blender to use it as a filter to record video as snapchat does it but with static png filters?

Comment: Not really png are static, i am looking for animated filters to add on top of recording video.

Comment: @johnconnor render as a png sequence with transparent background.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i will try it out and come back to tell if it worked.